# ListView items text are invisable

Tags: android, android-listview

My listview is being populated by cursor just fine I can see the listview row outlines but the text of each listview item is blank. I have an on click listener that uses a Toast msg that displays listview item and it works. It's like the text color of listview is the same as background making text invisible but I am not sure that's the issue.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Enter Data"
    android:onClick="onClickEnterData"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

sing_row_data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtRecid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Sample Data"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtUnitid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Sample Data 2"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.listviewcontroler;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.listviewcontroler.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MyActivity MA = new MyActivity() ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MA.displayList() ;
    }
}
```

container_for_listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/eq_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Your listview overlays on TextViews .ListView is on top of them

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the actual code you're running. You've passed `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, but it does not contain any of the IDs you've passed in the `to` array, so that would cause a crash. Furthermore, your `ListView` appears to be in the same layout you mean to use for its items, which is not what you want to do. Even if you've got the `Adapter` instantiation correct in the actual code, a `ListView` will be created in each item.

Comment: Every list item has its own layout file which should be inflated in case you are using  layout for list item

Answer (score 0):

Beside XML related problems, you are using a pre-designed row for your listView and yet you pass four items to it. It won't work like that. Since you want to show four texts in each row, you must create a custom Row and then pass that layout to your adapter.

I know there is a pre-designed row for two items like below, but not sure if there is any for 4!

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
    db.getAllTitles(), 
    new String[] { "first", "second" }, 
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
```

Comment: Ok I trimmed it back to two items but my listView items are still invisible.

Comment: Ok I edited code to what I have now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what it this method??
What does it do?? `MA.displayList() ;`